# how to get rid of #DIV/0! with IF()

Tags: excel, google-sheets-api

[help!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkD7Z.png)

Hi, I am new to excel or google sheets in general. I dont know where to start with adding the IF() function because the formula says =DataExport_2020!P1817. The original formula was L2/M2 and then I copied the formula down the entire column.

Comment: `IfError( YourFormula , ValueIfError )`,  eg `=IfError( L2/M2, "")`  Se [docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en)

Comment: =IfError( L2/M2, "0"), so I tried this but then the values turned 0 when it shouldnt?

Comment: The directions in your photo tell you to divide it by one instead of the total number of values.

Comment: "=IfError( L2/M2, "0")" so 0 is not text so remove the "" : =IfError( L2/M2,0). The other comment was using "" for blank.